# Sony UWP-D Audio Issues

Tags: audio, microphone, wireless, lavaliere

I have a Sony UWP-D Wireless Lav Mic set and I'm experiencing difficulties with audio in my office building. I can film any exterior shots with no issue. I also have no audio issues with audio within an enclosed staircase in a parking garage.

But when I use the UWP-D Mics when filming in my office building, the sound drops out every two or three seconds. Due to this only being observed in my office building (so far), I'm inclined to believe it's in the building and not the devices - but I'm more than willing to try any suggestions if anyone else has experienced the same issues with these or other wireless lav setups.

Answer (score 1):

After searching forums and YouTube videos, I believe I've found the culprit:

**My building's ultrasonic motion detectors.**

They emit an ultrasonic chirp every few seconds that the mics 'hear' and turn the volume down (attenuate?) for that portion.

I've contacted Sony Professional Equipment support and I've been issued a Beta Firmware upgrade for the transmitters (that's where the issue is, apparently) that's worked on one of my UTX-BO3's and my UTX-PO3.

The other BO3 got the firmware but has developed an issue where it can't stay on for more than 2 seconds on battery power. So it looks like I'll have to send it in. I'll update once I hear more.